# Does a kernels grid size determine the number of blocks, and the blocksize determine the numbers of threads?

Tags: cuda

I cant seem to understand the wording for the CUDA kernel parameters `<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>`

In the code I am reviewing they are defined as

```
const dim3 blockSize(1, 1, 1); 
const dim3 gridSize( 1, 1, 1);
```

Replacing the hardcoded 1s with variable reference, would they be properly name if they were named like so

```
const dim3 blockSize(nThreadsX, nThreadsY, nThreadsZ); 
const dim3 gridSize(nBlocksX, nBlocksY, nBlocksZ);
```

where the maximum value that any argument to `blockSize` can be is set by the hardware (something like 512 or 1024?) and is the maximum number of threads that will run in a block **in a single dimension**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the proposed naming is sensible.  Those `dim3` parameters are intended to represent (x,y,z) dimensions.  The block is composed of threads.  The grid is composed of blocks.

Using your naming, `nBlocksX`, `nBlocksY` and `nBlocksZ` must all be less than corresponding hardware-defined limits.  Those limits can be discovered from the [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications) (Table 12) or programmatically using a method such as that contained in the [deviceQuery](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#device-query) sample app.

There are similar limits for `nThreadsX`, `nThreadsY` and `nThreadsZ`, but *in addition*, the product `nThreadsX` * `nThreadsY` * `nThreadsZ` must also satisfy another limit ([Maximum number of threads per block](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications), which is either 512 or 1024 for current CUDA GPU hardware.